Proving $\frac{\sin\pi z}{z}$ is bounded in the punctured unit disk.
I want to prove that $f(z)=\frac{\sin \pi z}{z}$ is bounded in the unit disk. It has a removable singularity in $z=0$. This is because $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin \pi z}{z}=\frac{1}{\pi}$. From the Riemann removability condition there exists a punctured disk $\dot U_r(0)\subset \mathbb{C}^•$ such that f is bounded in it. For my homework I need to prove it for $r=1$. If $z\neq 0$ then :
$$\frac{\sin \pi z}{z}=\frac{ \pi z-\frac{(\pi z)^3}{3!}+\frac{ (\pi z)^5}{5!}-\ldots}{z}=\pi-\frac{(\pi z)^2}{3!}+\frac{ (\pi z)^4}{5!}-\ldots:=sinc(\pi z)$$ defines an analytic function which is also analytic in 0. This is the analytic continuation of f to $\mathbb{C}$ and is bounded on any compact set since it is also continuous. From the maximum modulus principle it follows that $sinc(\pi z)$ restricted to a domain $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ must attain its maximal modulus in the boundary since it is non-constant. An easy calculation shows that it occurs at $z=i$. This is because for any $z\neq 0$ : $sinc(\pi z)=\frac{\sin\pi z}{z}$. This proves that $sinc(\pi z)$ is bounded. Since $f= sinc_{|\mathbb{C^•}}$ , then f must also be bounded , because the restriction of a bounded function is still bounded. Is this correct? I think that I make the obvious very difficult for myself. The punctured unit disk is arcwise connected, open in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{C^•}$ and f is holomorphic in this set. Moreover f does not blow up if it approaches zero. Can we then state that f attains its maximum in the closure of the punctured unit disk with respect to the subspace topology of $\mathbb{C^•}$.

Where does the equality $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi z)=\sin(\pi z)$ come from?

This is because $z\neq 0$. And sinc($\pi z)= \frac{1}{\pi}$ if $z=0$ and equal to $\sin(\pi z)$ if $z\neq 0$.

Why? Isn't $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}z$ when $z\ne0$?

oh my bad that is what I actually meant

Besides, that's not the definition of $\operatorname{sinc}$. It should be$$\operatorname{sinc}(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin z}z&\text{ if }z\ne0\1&\text{ if }z=0.\end{cases}$$

Anyway, what is your question? Is it simply about how to prove that $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}z$ is bounded in the punctured unit disk?

Do you know that continuous functions are bounded on compact sets?

@JoséCarlosSantos Is there a faster way to prove this and is the last part in my question correct.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend yes that is what I used for the sinc function. How would I prove that for $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ since it is a function from $\mathbb{C^•}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Is it then true that the compact sets of $\mathbb{C^•}$ are exactly the compact set of $\mathbb{C}$ intersected with $\mathbb{C^•}$. If this is true than $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is bounded and doesn't blow up in zero in the punctured disk.

The singularity $0$ is removable due to the series expansion $\tfrac{\sin(z)}{z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tfrac{(-1)^k z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$. So your function has a holomorphic extension on $\mathbb{C}$.
